# F# filtering list

Tags: f#

How would I filter out a list by the index ?
List: [400; 5; 401; 6; 403; 7]
Filtered List: [5; 6; 7;]

I want to filter out the odd index numbers. So I could compare the values and then print out the largest value.

Comment: you can use `pairwise` with `snd`, a list comprehension, or `filter` with `mapi`.

Comment: @s952163 - `pairwise` with `snd` wouldn't work; `[1; 2; 3] |> List.pairwise` produces `[1,2 ; 2,3]`, so given any list with at least two items in it, `lst |> List.pairwise |> List.map snd` is equivalent to `lst |> List.skip 1`.

Comment: @rmunn you're absolutely right. I was thinking along the lines of `List.chunkBySize`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple and straight forward approach would be to recurse through the list and pick every second element:

```
let getOddIndexed list =
    let rec aux acc xs =
        match xs with
        | _::x::tail -> aux (x::acc) tail
        | _ -> acc |> List.rev
    aux [] list
```

Comment: A solution involving recursion is not a simple and straightforward one. The solution [you suggested below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49681860/f-filtering-list#comment86394850_49684622) is much simpler.

Answer (score 4):

In the specific case you asked about (keeping the odd index numbers and dropping the even ones), John Reynolds' answer will work. But in the general case where your index-based filter is more complicated, you'd want to use `Seq.indexed`, which turns any list of items into a list of (index, item) pairs. E.g.:

```
["apple"; "banana"; "cherry"] |> Seq.indexed |> List.ofSeq
// Produces [(0, "apple"); (1, "banana"); (2, "cherry")]
```

With this approach, you would then use `Seq.filter` to do the filtering you want, then turn the sequence back into a list at the end:

```
let keepOdd (idx, item) =
    // A more complicated filter might use the item parameter too
    idx % 2 <> 0

let input = [400; 5; 401; 6; 403; 7]
input |> Seq.indexed |> Seq.filter keepOdd |> List.ofSeq
```

Comment: `mapi` and `choose` is an alternative with fewer transformations: 
`input |> List.mapi (fun idx item -> if idx % 2 <> 0 then Some item else None) |> List.choose id`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution using foldBack

```
let folder x (index,lst) =
    if   index % 2 = 0
    then (index+1, x::lst)
    else (index+1, lst)

let list = snd (List.foldBack folder [400; 5; 401; 6; 403; 7] (0,[]))
```